# Adding a line in podfile in an expo managed project

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, react-native-firebase

I am trying to use `invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks` in my project but it implies modifying directly the ios podfile.

Is there a way in an expo managed project to add a specific line to a podfile ?

Comment: yes, you can create a config-plugin, read this https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/

Comment: Have you checked the above document (https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#modifying-the-ios-podfile)

Answer (score 2):

if you still needs this, here's the sollution:
first create a file `projectroot/plugins/withPodfile(or whatever you want).js`

then inside this file:

```
const { withDangerousMod, withPlugins } = require( '@expo/config-plugins' )
const fs = require( 'fs' )
const path = require( 'path' )

async function readFile( path ) {
  return fs.promises.readFile( path, 'utf8' )
}

async function saveFile( path, content ) {
  return fs.promises.writeFile( path, content, 'utf8' )
}

module.exports = ( config ) => withPlugins( config, [ ( config ) => {
  return withDangerousMod( config, [
    'ios',
    async ( config ) => {
      const file = path.join( config.modRequest.platformProjectRoot, 'Podfile' )
      /*
       * You need to remove the line before adding it.
       * If you don't do this and you run `expo prebuild` in a dirt project
       * your file will have the same line added twice
       */
      const contents = ( await readFile( file ) ).replace(
        /Write here the content you want to add...\n\n/g,
        ''
      )
      /*
       * Now re-adds the content
       */
      await saveFile( file, `Write here the content you want to add...\n\n${ contents }` )
      return config
    }
  ] )
} ] )
```

Now, to use the created plugin you just need to add it to plugins section inside your `app.json` or `app.config.js`:

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    plugins: [
      ... all your other plugins,
      "./plugins/withPodfile(your plugin file name)"
    ]
  }
}
```